# is swisseph package is mandatory for kerykeion?

Tags: python, python-module, python-3.9

I am using kerykeion library of python. My question is that when I am running kerykeion in my development environment, I am not getting any error but when I try to deploy something, I am getting error of swisseph package even though I installed pyswisseph package.

I installed swisseph from `pip install` cmd but still I am getting error that

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'swisseph'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```